# Редирект во фрейме

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, у меня возникла проблема и я не знаю как её решить, помогите пожалуйста.

Есть код:

```
<frameset rows="61,*">
<frame name="frminfo" scrolling="no" src="vls.php">
<frame name="frmsite" src="<?=$urlsite ?>">
</frameset>
```

В файле vls.php идёт отсчет таймера(20 сек), после того как 20 сек пройдёт, должен быть редирект на $urlsite, но у меня проблема вот в чём, что редирект происходит внутри фрейма(а не перезагружается вся страница меняя свой адрес). Как можно это исправить и сделать правильный редирект?

Comment: никак - ведь обработчик для фрейма, а не для всей страницы. Используйте ajax или просто поставьте таймер на javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript'ом. По истечении 20 секунд в vls.php должен выполниться примерно такой скрипт:

```
window.top.location.href = "http://sait.ru"; // сюда подставить url из $urlsite
```

Comment: Спасибо, сработало!)